# How to Retrieve from Checkbox Form Result with Adding [ in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, checkbox

For example I have code like this: $cities = "resultA, resultB, resultC, resultD, resultE";

Now, I want to retrieve the results to be like this : $finalcities = "[resultA] [resultB] [resultC] [resultD] [resultE]";

Is anybody can help me how to make it as I want? thanks.

Comment: don't understand what you are asking, can you provide more information.

Comment: Question is not clear.You need to provide more

Comment: Do you want to mach the results stored in a table  with form's checkbox data?

Comment: i'm so sorry.. but I have edited my question..

Answer (score 1):

Just one line of code.

```
 $cities = '['.str_replace(', ','] [', $cities).']';
```

We are replacing ', ', with '] [', so it will result in this

```
resultA][resultB][resultC][resultD][resultE
```

Now just add '[' and ']' to start and end.

Answer (score 0):

to convert the string

```
$cities = "resultA, resultB, resultC, resultD, resultE";
```

to

```
$finalcities = "[resultA] [resultB] [resultC] [resultD] [resultE]";
```

OPTION A

```
$finalcities = '['.str_replace(', ','] [',$cities).']';
```

simple [str_repalce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) of the, comma-space, separator plus the outer []

OPTION B

```
$finalcities = '['.implode('] [',explode(', ',$cities)).']';
```

little fancier, first split the string with [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) then glue it back together with [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Comment: `$finalcities = '['.str_replace(', ','[ ]',$cities).']';` won't work.

Answer (score -1):

Just add [ and ] bracket from start and end of the string and , will be replaced by ][ string.